# IIS 8.5 - Forms Authentication

Tags: c#, forms, authentication, iis-8.5

I've encountered what I think is a strange error with a C# project using .net framework 4 and forms authentication, running on IIS 8.5.

I'm able to create a form authentication cookie but I'm not able to 'sign out'. I've tried creating a manual `button` and calling `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` and I've also tried using the `LoginStatus` control.

Weird thing is that it works okay on the local Cassini server?

Anyone have any ideas? This one has been driving me insane!

Comment: what happens when you try to log out? is there an error message? what does the event viewer or your error logging say? you're going to need to give us more information other than "a strange error".

Comment: When we click the 'sign ou' link the page does a post back then comes back to exactly the same page (with the link still saying 'Sign Out').

Comment: I'll check the event viewer to see what information is logged there. Thanks for the pointers!